# NodeJs debug with WebStorm - org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.V8ProtocolReaderImpl$Mi cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.ValueHandle

Tags: node.js, volumio

I'm trying to debug a Remote NodeJs app (Volumio).

I'm able to set break points and step over the code, but when I try to inspect a value of any variable I get:

> org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.V8ProtocolReaderImpl$Mi cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.ValueHandle

I assume it's some version issues between the local and remote env,
but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In volumio ssh do:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same error debugging a different NodeJS application (based on MEAN.JS).  How does this solution fix the issue?